# Combine sparsely populated columns of the same data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I would like to combine columns 2,3,4,5 into just one column.

```
|  0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  90 |  90 |  A  |     |  A  |  A  |
| 101 | 101 |     |     |  T  |  T  |
| 245 | 246 |  AG |  AG |  AG |  AG |
| 302 | 302 |  C  |     |     |     |
| 324 | 324 |     |  G  |     |  G  |
```

Each column contains the same type of data but is sparsely populated. When all the columns are considered, each row would have an entry. So my goal here is to combine those columns together.

```
|  0  |  1  | new |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  90 |  90 |  A  |
| 101 | 101 |  T  |
| 245 | 246 |  AG |
| 302 | 302 |  C  |
| 324 | 324 |  G  |
```

Is there any way to do this in pandas or do I have to go row by row in pure python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.max(axis=1)` to calculate the column:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """ 90 ,  90 ,  A  ,     ,  A  ,  A 
101 , 101 ,     ,     ,  T  ,  T 
245 , 246 ,  AG ,  AG ,  AG ,  AG
302 , 302 ,  C  ,     ,     ,    
324 , 324 ,     ,  G  ,     ,  G """


df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None)
s = df.ix[:, 2:].max(axis=1)
df = df.ix[:, :1]
df["new"] = s
print df
```

result:

```
     0    1    new
0   90   90    A  
1  101  101    T  
2  245  246    AG 
3  302  302    C  
4  324  324    G
```